# Choosing an SSL certificate

Tags: rest, service, ssl, certificate, web

We are looking to get a wildcard SSL certificate for the company websites, and we are shocked to discover how messy the certificate market is.

Our sites will mainly be accessed in computer browsers. It isn't super important that the certificate is supported by mobile browsers, but it wouldn't hurt for it to be supported by at least newer smartphone browsers.

However, it is important that the certificate will work with mobile apps that we create (currently an Android app, but eventually iPhone and Windows Phone 7). These apps will access a REST web service using the wildcard certificate.

The cheapest wildcard certificate available on the Danish market is RapidSSL for about $100/yr. Will this fit our needs or do we need to go more expensive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

RapidSSL does not provide an extended validation certificate.

This is an example site (one of my test systems) with a RapidSSL certificate: https://leogarten.de/

If you open it with Chrome the URL has a green https tag. But with extended validation the URL gets a green box.

This is an example for such a site: https://www.paypal.com/de/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-run

Googles support pages explain the difference: https://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95617

Firefox 6 does not trust the RapidSSL certificate at all. IE 8 does not care much about security. I have no chance to test it with Safari.

Android does not trust the issuer. Tried it just with Android 2.1 (Motorola Defy). It could be different with other Android versions.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic. The issue isn't whether to get extended validation or not - we're already set on domain validation to keep costs low. Our main goal is to use SSL while avoiding browser warnings, and to make mobile app development relatively painless. I gather that it is possible to add certificates to an Android app installer, but it would of course be easier to use something that is already trusted by Android.